# python Mechanize 400 Bad Request

Tags: python, request, bots, bad-request

Hi i'm trying to code a bot for a browser game using Python and Mechanize library. I'm stuck with authentication step because when i try to submit a form i got 400 Bad Request with Python but it's fine with the browser

Python Code

```
from mechanize import Browser
import mechanize

browser = Browser()
browser.set_debug_http(True)
HEADERS = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Mobile Safari/537.36')]
browser.set_handle_equiv(True)
browser.set_handle_redirect(True)
browser.set_handle_referer(True)
browser.set_handle_robots(False)
browser.addheaders = HEADERS
browser.open('https://it.ogame.gameforge.com/')
browser.viewing_html()
browser.select_form(name='loginForm')
browser['login'] = 'email'
browser['pass'] = 'password'
response = browser.submit()
print(response.read())
```

Request debug response

```
send: 'POST /main/login HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nContent-

Length: 30\r\nConnection: close\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Mobile Safari/537.36\r\nHost: it.ogame.gameforge.com:443\r\nCookie: SID=rkq1jb7h8prj8hstsmgv3tkgv5\r\nReferer: https://it.ogame.gameforge.com/\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n\r\nkid=&login=email&pass=password'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
header: Date: Mon, 30 Jul 2018 21:39:52 GMT
header: Server: Apache
header: Vary: Accept-Encoding
header: Content-Length: 214
header: Connection: close
header: Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>400 Bad Request</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Bad Request</h1>
    <p>The request could not be understood by the server.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Website HTML (only part of form)

```
<form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" method="post" action="https://it.ogame.gameforge.com:443/main/login">
  <input type="hidden" name="kid" value="">

  <div class="input-wrap">
    <label style="display: inline-block; width: auto" for="usernameLogin">Indirizzo E-mail:</label>
    <a style="" tabindex="4" href="https://lobby.ogame.gameforge.com/retrieveAccountEmail?language=it" id="1emailLost" target="_blank" title="Indirizzo e-mail dimenticato?">(Indirizzo e-mail dimenticato?)</a>

    <div class="black-border">
      <input class="js_userName" type="text" tabindex="1" onkeydown="hideLoginErrorBox();" id="usernameLogin" name="login" value="">
      <div class="usernameLoginformError parentFormloginForm formError" style="opacity: 0.87; position: absolute; top: -2px; left: 385px; right: initial; margin-top: 0px;">
        <div class="formErrorContent">Il tuo indirizzo e-mail non è valido oppure la tua password non è corretta.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="usernameLogin_dialog" class="right">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="input-wrap">
    <label style="display: inline-block; width: auto" for="passwordLogin">Password:</label>
    <a style="" tabindex="4" href="https://lobby.ogame.gameforge.com/passwordReset?language=it" id="1pwLost" target="_blank" title="Password dimenticata?">(Password dimenticata?)</a>

    <div class="black-border">
      <input type="password" tabindex="2" onkeydown="hideLoginErrorBox();" id="passwordLogin" name="pass">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="input-wrap">
    <div id="autoLoginElement">
      <input type="checkbox" id="autoLogin" title="Login automatico">
      Login automatico
    </div>
    <p id="TermsAndConditionsAcceptWithLogin">
      Effettuando il login accetto le <a class="" href="https://agbserver.gameforge.com/rewrite.php locale=it&amp;type=switch&amp;product=ogame" target="_blank" title="T&amp;C">T&amp;C</a>.
    </p>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" id="loginSubmit" value="Login" tabindex="3">
```

Answer (score 0):

At first look seems that you are looking for the wrong method to write... when you set the value in your python code like this

```
browser['login'] = 'email'
browser['pass'] = 'password'
```

you should change it to

```
browser.form['login'] = 'email'
browser.form['pass'] = 'password'
```

according to the library docs: https://mechanize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/forms_api.html#mechanize.HTMLForm.set_value